# i don't know how to write this sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

i'm trying to write this query in postgresql...
i have this table:

```
id model lat lng alt last_track
1   x     4   4   4    20.30
1   x     4   5   2    19.15
0   y     5   2   1    20.31
0   y     1   8   4    20.00
```

and i would like to do a query that returns only the raw for each id, where the time is higher, so:

```
id model lat lng alt last_track
1   x     4   4   4    20.30
0   y     5   2   1    20.31
```

how can i do this? Thanks

Comment: Are you using native SQL or are you using an ORM tool like Hibernate?

Comment: This isn't related to java - please remove the tag.

Comment: @AndrewS ... unless the OP is using Postgres in its Java application

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - sure - but nothing in this particular question is related to java.

Answer (score 4):

For a native query option on Postgres, use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id, last_track DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
SELECT id, model, lat, lng, alt, last_track FROM mytable
WHERE last_track=(SELECT MAX(last_track) FROM mytable AS other WHERE other.id=mytable.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

`distinct on`-based solution is neat and concise yet Postgres-proprietary.
Here is SQL-standard solution using window functions:

```
select id, model, lat, lng, alt, last_track
from (
  select id, model, lat, lng, alt, last_track
       , row_number() over (partition by id order by last_track desc) as rn
  from t
) x
where x.rn = 1
```